# Python Trackbar not Updating Variable

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

Making a program to track a simple object and want to add in trackbars to dynamically change some of the image processing variables.

Trackbars aren't updating the thresh and bwthresh variables used for image processing in the while loop. Even after moving the trackbars, printing the values of thresh and bwthresh in the loop showed they were unaffected. I've tried making them global variables but that was to no avail. It looks to me like it should work, so I'm a bit stumped here.

```
max_thresh = 254
thresh = 100 #CHANGE THRESHOLD HERE
bwthresh = 250

cv.createTrackbar('BW thresh:', 'Code Test', bwthresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)
cv.createTrackbar('Canny thresh:', 'Code Test', thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)

while True:
    material, frame = capture.read()

    bwthreshnew = bwthresh
    threshnew = thresh

    print(bwthresh)
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (15,15))
    src_gray = cv.threshold(src_gray, bwthresh, max_thresh, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    
    cv.imshow('Other One', src_gray)

    thresh_callback(thresh)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('r'):
        break
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted is capable of changing `thresh` or `bwthresh` - passing them as parameters to `cv.createTrackbar()` only passes their initial values, it doesn't give that function any ability to change the variables.  Perhaps `thresh_callback()` changes the variables - I can't say because you didn't post the code to that rather important part of the problem - but I don't see how it could work properly, it has no way of knowing which trackbar was moved.

Comment: thresh_callback only changes a local variable to match it, so I can see why it wouldn't get updated. I tried changing the trackbars to call setters for bwthresh and thresh respectively, which did change those variables, which i made global.

However when I try to test-print bwthresh and thresh inside the while loop whilst changing them with the trackbar, they remain the same, even if I use a get function, so the values passed into the cv.threshold() function and thresh_callback() function are never changed somehow

Comment: [mre] required. we can't see your callback. if written correctly, it could change a global variable, or change a member of an object.